# Magento 2 refresh admin correct credentials

Tags: magento2, admin, login, credentials

I want to have a live Magento website (2.4.1) to my local machine but when I transferred the files from the server and downloaded the DB and go to the admin page he refreshes himself with no errors after I enters my credentials.

The steps I take:

- Download the magento files using any ftp client.
- Export the database from live server.
- Put the downloaded Magento files in your localhost root folder.
- Database replacers on .sql file with find old url and change to new url
- Create a blank database(lets say it 'local-database') in your local computer and import the database backup that you exported from the live one.
- Change app/etc/env.php

Terminal commands:
(i)Flush all cache
(ii)Re-Index all data
(iii)Flush all cache

I have a https connection locally and the website self is visible.

**Problem**
When I go to my admin page and enters the correct admin credentials the page is refreshing and nothing happened. No errors and noting in the logs. When I enters wrong credentials it also not giving any errors.

**What I have tried**

- Removing cache in the var folder
- Change permissions
- Checked the cookie fields in the config table in the DB
- Change vars input in .ini file
- Checked correct form key is used

Comment: Check cookies in core_config_data table with your website url and clear it

Comment: @Asssd I already tried but no effect

Comment: hi @JesseLafeber can you find any solution?